# Zooming in on pheatmap in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, pheatmap

I generated a heatmap of some single cell data (3285 cells x 6000 genes) using the pheatmap package on Rstudio. The columns are different individual cells, and the rows are different genes. I was able to find a pattern looking at the heatmap, and now I want to take a closer look at those sections. Is there anyway I could zoom in onto the regions of the heatmap squared in yellow other than just zooming in on the picture?

[image: heatmap]

Thank you so much!

Comment: There's not really a way to "zoom" in with the built in plot viewer. If you want to see a smaller region in more detail, you should just filter your data before plotting.

Comment: As @MrFlick said - you can't really zoom directly. Instead you can subest and replot. Because these are clustered heatmaps, those boxes are usually sub-trees of the dendrogram. Therefore, you can often use something like `stats::cutree()` to find those clusters in your data and then replot.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- `dplyr::select()` or `dplyr::filter()` the columns or rows that correspond to the parts you want to view and redraw the plot
- save the image as a vector image (e.g. .svg (the one I use), .eps, *etc.*) with `ggsave()` and then zoom-in at the saved image. Note that vector images such as .svg and .eps do not fragment into pixels.
- use completely different package that enables you to interact with the resultant output image, such as `library(heatmaply)`